# Checking webpacker is cause of for time sink

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, webpacker

Working on a ruby on rails application.

Let's say I make a small change to any class file and make a request to some page on my application. Then my response times are increased by anywhere from 20 seconds to 2-3 minutes or more.  The next request I make takes less than a second.

This issue happens only on local machine(not in production) when caching is turned off i.e this happens whenever `config.cache_classes = false` in `development.rb` is set to false.

I found out that one highly possible culprit for this time sink or delay is webpacker. How can I check if **webpacker** is the culprit for this time sink using the terminal log. If not possible with the terminal log, what are steps I can take to confirm that webpacker is responsible for the time sink.

If you feel webpacker is not the culprit. Please share your thoughts. Thank you for your time.

**UPDATE:-----------------------**

I have already tried enabling `config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker` in config/environments/development.rb The file_watcher setting resolved the issues when you are making only small 1-2 changes in your classes. If I am making many changes to many files at the same time(which is more realistic and likely) it makes the issue much worse. I had to wait close to 3 minutes for something that whould have taken 10-20 seconds without the setting change.

Comment: Check the development.log (`tail -f log/development.log`) . If it's webpacker you will see somethig like "Webacker is compiling.." if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @razvans You mean it will be stuck on "Webacker is compiling..."? Any possibility this output will not come in the terminal log?

Comment: Stuck until compilation is done, yes. It won't appear if you use dev-server. If you use it, and it's started, make sure you don't have anything else in public/packs except the manifest.json

Comment: @razvans 
1. How do I check if there is I use a dev-server? In bin folder there is a file called webpack-dev-server.rb Is that what you are talking about?
2. I checked public folder there is no folder/file named packs.

Comment: If you are asking #1 it means you are not using it. When you change css/js files, webpacker might be the problem because it recompiles. Usually this happes with big css/js bundles. But if your app is small, you don't change any js/css files, webpacker is not the problem. `development.log` should tell you more, why the app is slow.

Comment: Does this `config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker` help? Put it in `development.log`

Comment: @razvans The app takes the extra time when you make changes to the class files not when you change the view files. Also, The app is pretty large it has 200-300 models.
I enabled `config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker` in `development.rb` but what does it show in the terminal log?

Comment: Do you experience the same issues with that file_watcher setting?

Comment: @razvans The file_watcher setting resolved the issues when you are making only small 1-2 changes in your classes. If I am making many changes to many files at the same time(which is more realistic and likely) it makes the issue much worse. I had to wait close to 3 minutes for something that whould have taken 10-20 seconds without the setting change.